# Pass parameter for custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Using Angular 1.5 with components.

Some parent HTML that contains custom directive:

```
<my-thing resetFields='$ctrl.bReset'></my-thing>
```

EDIT: instead of `resetFields`, here I should have used `reset-fields` - this was why I got the undefined below.

Parent controller:

```
function parentController() {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.bReset= true;
        }
```

Here is the component declaration for myThing:

```
alert(ctrl.reset); // alert is called in controller, but shows undefined
function myThingComponent() {
            this.controller = {};
            this.bindings = {};
            var component = this;
            component.templateUrl = 'myThing.html';
            component.controller = myThingCtrl;
            component.transclude = true;
            component.bindings = {
                resetFields: '<' // one way binding is needed
            };
        }
```

How can I send such parameter and use it in the custom directive's controller - myThingCtrl?
If the reset value is true I will perform some action and on false another action.
(Generally the question I guess is - how can I read a value from the parent inside the child component.)

Comment: do you mean that `bReset` is a variable of your `$scope` ?

Comment: the parent component controller has the bReset value.

Comment: could you give us a minimal example (JSFiddle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achive this propouse you have create a directive like below:

```
angular.module("yourModule")
    .directive("myThing",function(){
        return {
            ...
            restrict : "E",
            scope:{
                    reset:"=reset",
                    ....
            },
            .....
            }
        }
    });
```

in component way

```
angular.module('yourModule').component('myThing', {
...
  bindings: {
    reset: '='
  }
});
```

The key point hear is use scope propertie like above and say that reset (reset in the left part) attribute in your directive is binded with a scope properties named reset (=reset rigth part) with the "=" you say that yoh have a two way data-binding.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: We are using components, we don't have modules? (I am new to these angular specifics)

Comment: I follow the official guide on the angular https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component and I see that use module for this

Comment: I am sitting on that page all day...no result yet. Now it seems like I can make progress.

Comment: you can refer with this in your controller is you use a scopeless app

Comment: yes it is scopeless I believe. I did all that and when alerting the value I still get undefined? Updated my question's code as well.

Comment: components are the new way for directives not modules

Comment: Seems to be working! I was using resetFields which is camel case, but I had to use reset-fields which will be translated to camel case on the custom directive.

Comment: of nothing it is been a pleasure for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from a simple directive I made that renders an animated counter.

```
function numberCounter($interval) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            start: '@start',
            end: '@end',
            speed: '@speed'
        },
        template: '<% number | number : 0 %>',
        link: link
    };

    ...
}
```

Then you can just use scope.start, scope.end, and scope.speed inside the link function. Start, end, and speed are attributes.